# Passing UISlider values from one ViewController to another

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uislider

I am working on AVSpeechSynthesizer and I am trying to pass values set on slider for volume, pitch and rate from settings view controller to main view Controller.
In settings View Controller, starting with the default values,

```
var volume : Float = 1.0
var pitch: Float = 1.0
var rate: Float = AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate
```

And slider actions,

```
@IBAction func volumeSliderDidSlide(_ sender: UISlider) {
    volume = sender.value
    testLable.text = String(volume)
}

@IBAction func pitchSliderDidSlide(_ sender: UISlider) {
    pitch = sender.value
}

@IBAction func rateSliderDidSlide(_ sender: UISlider) {
    rate = sender.value
}
```

In main view controller,

```
var ttsSettingsViewController: TTSSettingsViewController!

@IBOutlet weak var textBox: UITextView!
var speechSynthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
var speechUtterence : AVSpeechUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "TTS", bundle: nil)
    ttsSettingsViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TTSSettingsViewController") as! TTSSettingsViewController
}
@IBAction func didTapSpeech(_ sender: Any) {
    if let textBoxText = textBox.text{
        speechUtterence = AVSpeechUtterance(string: textBoxText)
        speechUtterence.volume = ttsSettingsViewController.volume
        speechUtterence.pitchMultiplier = ttsSettingsViewController.pitch
        speechUtterence.rate = ttsSettingsViewController.rate
        speechSynthesizer.speak(speechUtterence)
    }
}
```

But only the default values for volume, pitch and rate are being used, not the ones set on slider by changing.

Comment: It's a very common mistake. `TTSSettingsViewController()` creates a brand new instance which is **not** the instance in the storyboard and therefore the outlets are not connected.

Comment: @vadian Thank you for the correction, removed that line and this is how I instantiated:
        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "TTS", bundle: nil)
        ttsSettingsViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TTSSettingsViewController") as! TTSSettingsViewController
But I am still getting the default values.

Comment: How do you present your settingsController? Your code instantiates a controller but doing nothing with it, hence the default values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote some code that do same thing with your code.

In SettingViewController

```
class SettingViewController: UIViewController {

    var volume: Float = 0.0

    @IBAction func slider(_ sender: UISlider) {
        volume = sender.value
    }

    @IBAction func closeButton(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

and ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var settingVC: SettingViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        settingVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingViewController") as! SettingViewController
    }

    @IBAction func printSettingValue(_ sender: Any) {
        // Use setting view controller's value
        print(settingVC.volume)
    }

    @IBAction func showSettingView(_ sender: Any) {
        show(settingVC, sender: nil)
    }
}
```

So, this is my code, and this works well.

There is my hypotheses.TTSSettingsViewController's values that you used might be different values that you changed.

Comment: Yes I had problem with values, initially changed values were not being used.
Thank you.